# Google Sheets API V4 adding new row of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The documentation says:

> *"The Sheets API v4 does provide an AppendCells request that can be used with the spreadsheets.batchUpdate method to append a row of data
>   to a sheet (and simultaneously update the cell properties and
>   formatting, if desired). However, it is usually easier to simply
>   determine the A1 notation of the row you wish to add, and then issue a
>   spreadsheets.values.update request to overwrite that row."*

How do you determine the A1 notation of the row you wish to add and/or how does the AppendCells request get made? I'm using php.